# How can I match points for best fit from one list to another?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a list of points, internal chessboard corners actually from a picture taken at a roughly 45-50 degree angle.

[Viewpoint of real board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5a2k.jpg)

I have another list of points, this time from a birds eye view of an unoccupied board.

[model of board with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxpXQ.png)

There are 49 points from the 2nd list, and there are a variable amount of points in the first list, ranging from 20-49 depending on occlusions, lighting and various other factors.

My question is this... Is there any method I should use to match the points together to find the ***best fit***

Model points :

```
[(119, 118), (359, 118), (599, 118), (839, 118), (239, 238), (479, 238), (719, 238), (119, 358), (359, 358), (599, 358), (839, 358), (239, 478), (479, 478), (719, 478), (119, 598), (359, 598), (599, 598), (839, 598), (239, 718), (479, 718), (719, 718), (119, 838), (359, 838), (599, 838), (839, 838), (239, 118), (479, 118), (719, 118), (119, 238), (359, 238), (599, 238), (839, 238), (239, 358), (479, 358), (719, 358), (119, 478), (359, 478), (599, 478), (839, 478), (239, 598), (479, 598), (719, 598), (119, 718), (359, 718), (599, 718), (839, 718), (239, 838), (479, 838), (719, 838)]
```

Detected points:

```
[(580, 188), (918, 188), (750, 191), (847, 239), (402, 240), (493, 241), (670, 241), (581, 242), (487, 298), (581, 298), (674, 298), (874, 360), (679, 362), (786, 433), (683, 435), (476, 436), (581, 437), (371, 439), (908, 511), (689, 513), (580, 516), (470, 517), (357, 518), (1046, 598), (811, 601), (695, 603), (579, 604), (461, 606), (344, 609)]
```

I thought about normalising the points between 0-1 by dividing them by the size of the model, however I would only have the dimension data available from the model, not the detected points as they could be anywhere within the image frame.

I also have tried to iterate through the points and find how many points are within a pre-set region from the current point when iterating through the points and then this would give me some "features", such as neighbourhood points...

I have tried something like this...

```
pointFeatures = []
        ptNum = 0
        for pt in model_points:
            inRangePoints = 0
            for i in range(len(model_points)):
                if euclidean1(pt, model_points[i]) < 150:
                    if pt != model_points[i]:
                        inRangePoints += 1
            pointFeatures .append((ptNum, inRangePoints, pt))
```

I get the following information for the model points...

```
[(0, 2, (119, 118)), (1, 3, (359, 118)), (2, 3, (599, 118)), (3, 2, (839, 118)), (4, 4, (239, 238)), (5, 4, (479, 238)), (6, 4, (719, 238)), (7, 3, (119, 358)), (8, 4, (359, 358)), (9, 4, (599, 358)), (10, 3, (839, 358)), (11, 4, (239, 478)), (12, 4, (479, 478)), (13, 4, (719, 478)), (14, 3, (119, 598)), (15, 4, (359, 598)), (16, 4, (599, 598)), (17, 3, (839, 598)), (18, 4, (239, 718)), (19, 4, (479, 718)), (20, 4, (719, 718)), (21, 2, (119, 838)), (22, 3, (359, 838)), (23, 3, (599, 838)), (24, 2, (839, 838)), (25, 3, (239, 118)), (26, 3, (479, 118)), (27, 3, (719, 118)), (28, 3, (119, 238)), (29, 4, (359, 238)), (30, 4, (599, 238)), (31, 3, (839, 238)), (32, 4, (239, 358)), (33, 4, (479, 358)), (34, 4, (719, 358)), (35, 3, (119, 478)), (36, 4, (359, 478)), (37, 4, (599, 478)), (38, 3, (839, 478)), (39, 4, (239, 598)), (40, 4, (479, 598)), (41, 4, (719, 598)), (42, 3, (119, 718)), (43, 4, (359, 718)), (44, 4, (599, 718)), (45, 3, (839, 718)), (46, 3, (239, 838)), (47, 3, (479, 838)), (48, 3, (719, 838))]
```

Could I use the "number of neighbour" points to fit a ***best fit*** for the data? Would the fact that I have missing data points and an uneven amount of points make any different for my problem?

I have tried using, SIFT, ORB, FLANN etc.... to no avail.

I am open to suggestions.

Comment: your task is a bit unclear to me. From convex hull you can find the outer-most points and the corners, but the board is symmetric, right? From 4 or more correspondences you can compute a homography that should work for all the other points? So there is some ambiguity. But it's not clear to me whether you have all inner chessboard points or only a subset. Just from a subset you should have no idea where you are inside of the board since it is a repeated pattern...

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have used convex hull around intersection points in a different implementation I did, however it doesn't solve anything if it doesn't get all the points/corners, I get a wildly inaccurate representation of the board. To clarify, I have ALL 49 points from the model I create of a board, however I get anywhere from 20-49 points for the detected points from an image. You are correct I have ZERO clue where the points from the detection are and that is the question I have.... I want to find the best MATCH for the points in the "model" point set.

Comment: you could try homography computation with some RANSAC and all possible matchings or use the knowledge of your scenario/pattern like the smallest distance of all points is probably a single edge in your chessboard. But in the end, each found "best" matching is still ambiguous for 90°, 180° and 270° rotations, even if you have detected all 49 points.

Comment: if you want to go the "try all possible matchings at the same time with ransac" you can probably use the domain knowledge and convex hull to remove a lot of impossible matching combinations in the beginning, because of their spatial relationship.

Comment: and I remember something from my AI classes, afair some kind of markov thing. You can maybe interpret your detections as a time series. Your first point has uniform probability to be any of the chessboard corners. Until the 4th point the probability will be fixed because of arbitrary perspective, unless more than 2 points are on a line. From the 5th point on, the probability of your first 4 point's position/matching will be lowered for wrong positione/matchings and increased for "good" positions.